# Why does Archer hate cyborgs?

Tags: tv, cyborg, archer

I don't know the show well enough to know if Barry was the first cyborg Archer met, but it is obvious that he despises cyborgs, and I was wondering if we ever learn why this is the case.

> ARCHER: **Ray’s gonna be a cyborg
>
>   over my dead body!
>
>   Or preferably his!
>
>   But somebody’s!**
>
> ARCHER: Krieger! Krieger!
>   Krieger open this goddamn door!
>   Krieger I am gonna count to one!
>   PAM: **Oh that’s right,
>
>   he hates robots!**
>   KRIEGER: For the —
>   this! Is a robot!
>   Gillette is a human being!
>   But he won’t be for long if you
>   don’t clamp that artery!
>   ARCHER: One!
>   -*Archer, Season 4 Episode 3, "Legs".*

Does he hate them because of Barry, or because of his fear of a Terminator-esque war against the machines, or for some other reason?

Comment: Note:  This is the first question about Archer, and is a sort of trial run for the new tag.

Comment: Best answer: Yes.

Comment: Because it is funny

Comment: Quotes and/or screenshots from Archer should make the family-friendly boundaries of this site... interesting.

Comment: His hatred of cyborgs is without a doubt due to the Archer vs Barry rivalry...

Comment: "I don't know the show well enough", then just watch and rewatch and rewatch, until you do. C'mon Wad Cheber, read a book! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all about Barry and Archer watching too many sci-fi movies about Skynet-like things.

Barry has done multiple wrongs to Archer, so many it turned into a war, and I've honestly lost count a long time ago.

As for the movies, let's remember Archer is still pretty childish and gets caught up in his imagination and fears, leading him to believe the things depicted in the movies have to be prevented. Multiple scifi references clearly tell us that.

Also, as @asawyer mentioned, the vacuum cleaner incident.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the vacuum cleaner nozzle / penis childhood incident.

Comment: @asawyer I've completly forgotten about this

Answer (score 2):

As you may know that Archer and Barry Dillon do not get along.

The reason that Archer hates cyborgs is because Archer was about to get married to a former KGB agent named Katya Kaznova. At the wedding Barry shows up as a cyborg and throws Katya off his penthouse killing her. In season 3 Krieger revives Katya by turnung her into a cyborg. foolishly he uses equipment from the KGB which allowed Barry to track Archer to the ISIS building.At Archer and Katya's second wedding both Katya and Barry fight which leads them into having sex. Katya tells Archer that she is better off with Barry because they are the same which leaded Barry and Katya running off together.

That's why Archer hates cyborgs

Oh and when Archer was young he put his penis in a vacuum causing him to go to the emergency room